# How to add new line between `ls -l` output

Tags: ls

This is standard `ls -l` output.

```
user@linux:~$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file01
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file02
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file03
user@linux:~$
```

Would it be possible to add new line like this?

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file01

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file02

-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 0 Nov   1 00:00 file03
```

Comment: But why? If it is to make it more readable, then consider changing to a different font, and different line spacing.

Comment: I agree with the above question. Please provide some rationale for your *issue*. Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
ls -l | sed G
```

(that one is a common idiom and [on the `sed` FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.2)).

Or (likely faster, probably doesn't matter for the (likely short) output of `ls -l`):

```
ls -l | paste -d '\n' - /dev/null
```

Those insert a blank line after each *line* of the output of `ls -l`.

Now, if you want an empty line after each file described by `ls -l`, which would be different if there are files whose name contains newline characters, you would have to do something like:

```
for f in *; do ls -ld -- "$f" && echo; done
```

(which would also skip the `total` line).

Or you could use `ls -ql` which would make sure you get one line per file (the newline characters, like all control characters would be rendered as `?` (at least in the POSIX locale)).

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
ls -l | awk '{printf "%s\n\n", $0}'
```

Comment: ... or perhaps more idiomatically, `ls -l | awk 1 ORS='\n\n'`

Comment: Or `ls -l | awk '{print  $0 "\n"}'`

Answer (score 4):

```
NAME
       pr - convert text files for printing
```

Interleaving with single empty line, w/o adding header:

`… | pr -dt`

Comment: Note that `pr` also treats formfeed characters specially in its input (with the behaviour varying between implementations)

Answer (score 2):

One more:

```
ls (options) | while read LINE; do
  echo "$LINE
"
done
```

Comment: Use `read -r` to treat backslashes literally

Comment: Since there are no backslashes in my script nor in OP's question, this is irrelevant.

Comment: Sure, but if you come across a file called `\a` for example, it will be printed as `a`. It may be rare, but `read -r` will avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: it also won't work for filenames that contain new lines. There's a reason why [`ls` output shouldn't be piped for further processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Comment: @wjandrea, [the syntax to read a line is actually `IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123). `echo` also [can't be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803). In any case [using a shell loop to process text is generally a bad idea](/q/169716)

Comment: And yet such loops have almost never been a problem for me (a retired software engineer).   The point about special characters is valid, but putting such characters in file names is rarely easy and never smart.